# How do you extend the item:new command without breaking a previous patch for it?

Tags: content-editor, commands

In my example, Sitecore PowerShell Extensions (SPE) patches the command in order to provide insert options.

Reviewing the *ShowConfig.aspx* I see the following:

```
<command name="item:new" type="Cognifide.PowerShell.Client.Commands.MenuItems.ItemNew, Cognifide.PowerShell" patch:source="Cognifide.PowerShell.config"/>
```

My concern is that when I patch over the same command name SPE will break.

Is there a way to support multiple command implementations? Perhaps this would make a great module!

### Update 1

Based on Mark's feedback I came up with this quick script to determine what might be possible. The script just queries the items that are already in the list. Perhaps I could use this to determine if I should add more items to the list. Also, not sure how I could add my own dividers.

```powershell
$commandName = "item:new"
$item = Get-Item -Path "master:" -ID "{A3572733-5062-43E9-A447-54698BC1C637}"
$commandContext = New-Object -TypeName Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.CommandContext -ArgumentList $item

[Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.CommandManager]::GetCommand($commandName).GetSubMenuItems($commandContext) | 
    Where-Object { $_.GetType().Name -eq 'MenuItem' } | Select-Object -Property header
```

[image: Output]

Here's what I think might work.

1. Create a new insert options with condition and action to render the desired items.
2. Figure out what happens when the user click the insert option.

### Update 2

I found a solution by writing a module for it. See the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a solution, but required some light coding to get working. I've created a module for this solution in case anyone wants to do this without duplicating effort. Check it out [here](https://github.com/michaellwest/westco-ss-commandextender).

The solution involves a few steps.

1. Override the `ItemNew` command with an implementation that will render the submenu for other classes.
2. Patch the command with the list of class names.

Here's a single patch to both override the `ItemNew` command and add in the list of classes.

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <commands>
      <command name="item:new">
        <patch:attribute name="type">Westco.SS.Foundation.CommandExtender.Commands.ItemNew, Westco.SS.Foundation.CommandExtender</patch:attribute>
        <menucommands hint="list">
          <menucommand type="Cognifide.PowerShell.Client.Commands.MenuItems.ItemNew, Cognifide.PowerShell" />
          <menucommand type="Sitecore.SharedSource.Shell.Framework.Commands.MenuItems.ItemNew, Sitecore.SharedSource.CodeEditor" />
        </menucommands>
      </command>
    </commands>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

As you can see, SPE is installed and the Code Editor module is still able to render the items.

[image: Sample]

Answer (score 4):

Not easily, no.

Commands are bound to that identifier string (e.g. `"item:new"`) and that's how they are identified across the system.

You could override (replace) by inheriting the PowerShell command and calling it via `base.`.

### Another option

And perhaps the better one, if you need Insert Options, is to use the Rules Engine.

Depending on your specific use case, even out-of-the-box you have the ability to dynamically add Insert Options.

[image]

You can then extend this with custom Conditions and Actions as needed.